# Python Request HTTPAuth does not work when using secrets from AWS SecretsManager

Tags: python, request, jira, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to make a POST request to Jira to create an issue using the request library. I am getting the Jira email and API key through SecretsManager. Here's my code:

```
        JIRA_URL = "https://<jira-url>.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/"
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        
        field = {
            "fields": {
                "summary": summary,
                "project": {
                    "id": JIRA_PROJECT_ID
                },
                "issuetype": {
                    "id": ISSUE_ID
                },
                "assignee": {
                    "id": secrets["JIRA_ACCOUNT_ID"]
                },
                "description": {
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "text": content,
                                    "type": "text"
                                }
                            ],
                            "type": "paragraph"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "doc",
                    "version": 1
                },
            }
        }

        payload = json.dumps(field)
        response = requests.request("POST", JIRA_URL, headers=headers, auth=(secrets["JIRA_EMAIL"], secrets["JIRA_API_KEY"]), data=payload)
        print(response.json())
```

The issue is not created and the `response.json()` does not event print. But when I hardcode my secrets, it works. Why is this happening?

EDIT: I did get this error:

> Failed to run an internal function (cannot unpack non-iterable int object) Failed to run an internal function (cannot unpack non-iterable int object)

The `secrets` variable is defined below.

```
secrets = secrets_manager.get_secret()

def get_secret():
    secret_name = "<<name>>"
    region_name = "<<region_name>>"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        # For a list of exceptions thrown, see
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
        raise e

    # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
    secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])

    return secret
```

Comment: Where are you defining `secrets` ? What is the error you are getting? Please make sure there is enough code and information so that the problem can be understood/reproduced.